# unbound method when using type builtin to create a dynamic object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have this code:

```
class X(object):
    x = 10
    def test_x(self):
        return self.x

class Y(X):
    def test_y(self):
        return self.x

y = Y()
y.test_y()      # works fine
```

But when I construct a new object z based on X using type :

```
z = type('Z', (X,), dict(z=1))
z.x             # works fine
z.test_x()      # gives a TypeError :
```

unbound method test_x() must be called with Z instance as first argument (got nothing instead).
How can I solve it.

**UPDATE**

With the help and understanding of Martijn, this is how I solved it:

```
z = type('Z', (X,), dict(z=1))()
z.test_x()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`z` is a class, not an instance. Create an instance instead:

```
z().test_x()
```

What you did was the equivalent of:

```
class Z(X):
    z = 1

z = Z
z.test_x()
```

Comment: @Martijn: z is a object not a class. As I show z.x works fine, but z().test_x() returns : AttributeError: 'Z' object has no attribute 'text_x'

Comment: @voscausa: `type(z)` -> `<type 'type'>`. But so are `X` and `Y`. They are all python classes. My answer had a small typo; I corrected it (`test_x` vs. `text_x`).

Comment: @Martijn: Yes, but again z.x works fine and z().text_x() gives an error. The docs say: With three arguments, return a new type object.

Comment: @voscausa: that's what python classes are. `z.x` is the *class* attribute. Try `X.x` next, it also works. `z().test_x()` works (note the difference)!

Comment: @voscausa: I suspect that you mostly got confused because you stored the result of the `type()` constructor in a variable called `z` (lowercase). You can store it in a variable `Z` just as easily (uppercase). It'll not change the type of object returned.

Comment: @Martijn. You are very right. I'am sorry for misunderstanding you and mistyping your aswer